# rounding numerical output inside append text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function and want to round the output in the appended text `text(i * 12.2)`.  I have tried using `text(round(i * 12.2)));` but the function fails.  So how can I round the output to an integer and put that into the append?

```
function drawRuler(){
    $(".ruler[data-items]").each(function() {
        var ruler = $(this).empty(),
            len = Number(ruler.attr("data-items")) || 0,
            item = $(document.createElement("li")),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ruler.append(item.clone().text(i * 12.2));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: looking for `Math` object...`Math.round()`

Comment: OK, how would I use that in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl mentioned in the comment, all you need to do is change

```
ruler.append(item.clone().text(i * 12.2));
```

to

```
ruler.append(item.clone().text(Math.round(i * 12.2)));
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Yep, thanks although it's not giving me the output that I was expecting.  I guess I need to work on it a bit more, I'll ask another question if I need to. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterBrowne I think you can tweak that. The important thing here was round is a function under Math.